# Sections of desktop turn black?

Tags: macos, imac, screen

So I have a very odd issue. At random I get black sections in program windows, on dock icons, and on my desktop. What makes it odd is I can actually take a screenshot of it plus you can even see it through other visual elements such as the menu bar and dock and moving the mouse or a window over the area does not "erase" it. I've completely zero filled the hard drive and then reinstalled OS X Lion 10.7.5 11G63 however it didn't fix it. Yet booting into Linux Lubuntu 14.04.1 64bit has no visual issues at all.

Does anyone else have this issue or know how to solve it? It doesn't seem focused on any one wallpaper (I have 10+ from varying websites) or application. This is on my Late 2006 iMac, Core 2 Duo 2.0GHz, 4GB RAM, ATI Radeon X1600 128MB.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
(black bar over user name was done by me, everything else was not)
I ran multiple extended tests in AHT thanks to [this guide](http://rivenbyfive.blogspot.com/2012/01/download-and-run-apple-hardware-test.html), however it could not find anything wrong.
[image]

Comment: I was going to suggest updating to the latest OS, but since your Mac is older, I'd recommend just downloading the OS X 10.7.5 installer combo. Here's the link: [https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1582?locale=en_US](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1582?locale=en_US)

Comment: I am already running 10.7.5 however.

Comment: sometimes things get messed up, and you need to reinstall OS X. Reinstalling the latest update won't hurt.

Comment: A complete hard drive zero fill and then install of OS X 10.7.5 11G63 (the absolute latest version of Lion) which passed image verification did not resolve the issue.

Comment: can you try plugging your Mac into a different monitor?

Comment: Since it does not use a standard connector for external monitors I can't, I don't have anything that plugs into it. I wouldn't expect there to be a difference since I can take screenshots of the issue though.